# How can I find all of my answers where there's another answer on the same question?

Tags: support, search

On Stack Overflow I'm trying to search `user:1075247 answers:2 is:question` but it's bringing up answers on *my questions*, not *my answers* on others questions.

Is there a way to perform this search without resorting to SEDE?

Comment: I don't think that can be done with on-site search because with is:question or answers:2 you bring in question as the main post to have any criteria to be applied to. `users:me` will then be applied to the question. You can only do this with SEDE, or if you like the StackAPI, with some api calls and scripting the results.